# Erro ao usar o chatterbot no python ('chatterbot' is not a package)

Tags: python, chatbot, chatterbot

Fiz um código básico de Chatterbot no Python que rodava bem, mas do nada parou de funcionar e sempre apresenta o mesmo erro:

> from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chatterbot.trainers'; 'chatterbot' is not a package

Por favor, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Ele não encontrou o pacote `chatterbot`. Certifique-se que está instalado e que você está executando o Python na mesma versão que o pacote foi instalado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse problema [já foi relatado e resolvido no *StackOverflow em inglês*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52136655).

Isso pode estar sendo causado pelo fato de esse arquivo que você está executando, ou algum outro arquivo que está no mesmo diretório, ter o mesmo nome do módulo. Desse modo, ele causará esse erro, pois, como diz no enunciado: *'chatterbot' não é um pacote*.

Em suma: mude o nome do arquivo de *"chatterbot"* para outro nome.

No entanto, se isso não parar os erros em relação ao módulo, então, como o @Woss falou, você deve se certificar de que tem o *chatterbot* instalado.

Espero ter ajudado!